# How to use Visual Studio Code with Haskell and Docker

Tags: linux, docker, haskell, visual-studio-code

A lot of people use Visual Studio Code. Very common scenario today is to use Docker. So, I have some Haskell code in the Docker with "stack" tool - all is fine, I build my project without errors. I can use Visual Studio Code with Haskell on my host machine (with different extensions, for example, Haskelly works mostly good). It happens under some user account. Now I want to work with my Haskell project which is in Docker, where my account is root. So, I installed "Docker Workspace" extension. It works, truth: I can add some folder from the docker as a workspace and to edit files from it. But no any Haskell support, only highlight: no types hints, nothing ("Type not available" and similar)! As I can see, Haskelly cannot work with a project in the Docker OR *I do something wrongly*. The scheme is:

```
ON HOST - owner "user"     .      IN DOCKER - owner "root"
----------------------     .      ------------------------
myproj/                    .      myproj/
  .stack-work              .        .stack-work
  all-other-files          .        all-other-files
                           .                |
                           .                |
 Visual Studio Code <----Docker Workspace---'
                           .
                           .
```

I mount the folder of my project in the docker (I share it between host and Docker). Project cannot be built outside of Docker due to .so dependencies. So, Visual Studio Code on the host open Docker folder, if I will open the same `myproj/` in the host - Haskell extension cannot work because the compiler cannot build the project - no .so dependencies.

When I opened files from the Docker, I supposed all extensions will work with Docker - if it starts "stack" then it will try to do it in the docker. This seems like a silly assumption, so my question is: **"how to work with a project in such a scenario?"**. I think it's a problem not related to Haskell and extensions for other languages will hit the same problem but sure, if the problem has solution then it will be specific for Haskelly/Haskell... And I am sure a lot of people use Visual Studio Code and Docker in such a scenario, but I have not idea how to do it correctly.

I found these errors in the logs:

```
[2020-01-21 08:55:02.086] [exthost] [error] [UCL.haskelly] provider FAILED
[2020-01-21 08:55:02.086] [exthost] [error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null
    at InteroLocationDecoder.extractRange (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/InteroLocationDecoder.js:24:13)
    at InteroLocationDecoder.buildLocation (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/InteroLocationDecoder.js:11:28)
    at InteroLocationDecoder.decode (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/InteroLocationDecoder.js:6:21)
    at HaskellDefinitionProvider.<anonymous> (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/Definition/index.js:24:47)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/Definition/index.js:4:58)
```

and

```
[2020-01-21 09:41:52.995] [exthost] [error] [UCL.haskelly] provider FAILED
[2020-01-21 09:41:52.995] [exthost] [error] Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:413:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:401:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:301:11)
    at InteroSpawn.<anonymous> (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/InteroSpawn.js:190:30)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/InteroSpawn.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/InteroSpawn.js:3:12)
    at InteroSpawn.executeCommandOnIntero (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/InteroSpawn.js:186:16)
    at InteroSpawn.requestDefinition (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/InteroSpawn.js:170:21)
    at HaskellDefinitionProvider.<anonymous> (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/Definition/index.js:23:63)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/Definition/index.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/Definition/index.js:3:12)
    at HaskellDefinitionProvider.provideDefinition (/home/xyz/.vscode/extensions/ucl.haskelly-0.5.5/out/src/Providers/Definition/index.js:20:16)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:574:358
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:52:287
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.t.asPromise (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:52:259)
    at y.provideDefinition (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:574:329)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:593:526
    at B._withAdapter (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:591:697)
    at B.$provideDefinition (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:593:504)
    at p._doInvokeHandler (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:663:275)
    at p._invokeHandler (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:662:971)
    at p._receiveRequest (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:661:588)
    at p._receiveOneMessage (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:660:468)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:658:691
    at l.fire (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:46:893)
    at _.fire (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:189:274)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:820:285
    at l.fire (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:46:893)
    at _.fire (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:189:274)
    at t.PersistentProtocol._receiveMessage (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:193:629)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:190:824
    at l.fire (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:46:893)
    at p.acceptChunk (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:186:737)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:186:89
    at Socket.t (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:195:68)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:210:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17)
```

but I am not sure that they are related to the problem because I reloaded Visual Studio Code and did not see them again.

I supposed the root of the problem is permissions (if some files were build/compiled in the Docker then they are not accessible on host - they are owned now by root), so I changed owner (`sudo chown -R xyz .`) but Haskelly extension still does not work. I don't know a way to compile the project in the Docker but to use the result (Haskell extensions require the code to be compiled - `.stack-work/`) on the host, because the extension wants to recompile it... I will be grateful for any links to documentation, forum, blog with the solution.

Comment: Stack already gives you a fairly isolated development environment on the host, and can do things like install specific versions of ghc for you.  What additional benefits are you hoping to get from using Docker?

Comment: It's a common scenario in my team: for example, we use the last postgresql (with libpq). Usually you avoid to install all bunch of services with their dependencies locally - you prefer Docker/Docker compose, so...

Comment: This was a life saver for me hope it helps https://medium.com/@dogwith1eye/try-haskell-with-vs-code-remote-containers-77cac030dd5f

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/melias77/haskell-developer_box. @David. Don't pollute your host machine and virtual machines to tedious and slow to bring up. Use containers whenever you can, its fast and easy.

Comment: Just adding that I was running into similar issues and removing the `docker:` field in my `stack.yaml` instantly solved all of them... so it seems Docker is definitely the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried HIE under Docker and hit a lot of problems, so I am not sure that it works in all setups/environments. So, I found another method to work with Haskell project inside Docker under Visual Studio Code.

First, I installed stack (for a build of the project), then I install ghc (and ghci) inside Docker (example is based on Debian image):

```
...
ARG STACK_VERSION="2.1.3"
ARG STACK="stack-${STACK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz"

RUN mkdir -p /root/.local/bin
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  # stack dependencies taken from this script "https://get.haskellstack.org/"
  curl g++ gcc libc6-dev libffi-dev libgmp-dev make xz-utils zlib1g-dev git gnupg netbase \
  mc \
  libicu-dev libtinfo-dev # they are maybe optional
...
RUN curl -sSLO "https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/download/v${STACK_VERSION}/${STACK}" \
    && echo "4e937a6ad7b5e352c5bd03aef29a753e9c4ca7e8ccc22deb5cd54019a8cf130c ${STACK}" | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar --strip=1 -xzf "${STACK}" -C ~/.local/bin "stack-${STACK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64-static/stack" \
    && rm ${STACK}

ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/.local/bin

RUN mv /root/.local/bin/stack /root/.local/bin/stack.orig
RUN echo '#!/bin/sh' >> /root/.local/bin/stack
RUN echo '/root/.local/bin/stack.orig --allow-different-user $*' >> /root/.local/bin/stack
RUN chmod +x /root/.local/bin/stack
RUN /root/.local/bin/stack install --resolver=lts-13.20 ghc ghci
...
```

I use LTS-13.20. The next, I created folder ".devcontainer/" in the root of my project (where is "package.yaml" file) with one file there "devcontainer.json":

```
{
  "name": "HaskelInDocker",
  "dockerFile": "../../Dockerfile.vscode",
  "appPort": 9000,
  "startup":true,
  "extensions": [
    "dramforever.vscode-ghc-simple"
  ]
}
```

You should change path to Dockerfile in "dockerFile" property to yours. After it, I created my Docker image as usual and then I ran Visual Studio Code, selected the command "Remote-Containers: Open Folder In Container..." and chose the root of my project as a folder. VSCode started the Docker container (you can check it with `docker ps`) under some weird name prefixed with "vcs-" (in my case) and started to build the project. You should wait until it ends. Then you can set cursor on some function and you will see the types hint - the extension work! All messages from this extension can be found with `CTRL-SHIFT-P` then `Show Logs...` then select "GHC" in logs list box. More details about `dockercontainer` mechanism can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers).

PS. This Docker extension supports also attaching to existing (running) container - tested, it works fine...

Answer (score -1):

try this haskell developer box, vscode works like charm. Bind mount folders also works.

https://hub.docker.com/r/melias77/haskell-developer_box